# Ionic 2 build android error -- gradle-wrapper.properties File not find

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new to `Ionic` and I am trying to build an `android apk` using the command `ionic build android`.

However, there is an error:

[image]

It said "gradle-wrapper.properties File not find", I tried to copy `gradle-wrapper.properties` from android studio to the current dir, 
it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to remove the platform then add again?

```
ionic platform rm android
ionic platform add android@6.1.0
ionic build android
```

'@6.1.0' is the stable Cordova-android version that I'm using in my published app.

Comment: Yes. Try re-adding the platform. Or as @Djamware suggests, add a stable android platform.

Comment: I tried these commands, but when I execute the `ionic platform add android@6.1.0`, the same error is coming out again. Is it the `Gradle` version problem? I using `Gradle 3.3`

Comment: I think it's related to android sdk

Comment: yes. Maybe it is the sdk problem, I am trying to find out.

Comment: I reinstall all the SDK and reset the PATH and it is work now. Thx a lot ;)